# How to play video (swf) in chm file created in robohelp?

Tags: video, html-helper, chm, robohelp

I use robohelp 9 to make chm help file. I put "hyperlink" to video on my computer, and when try to "View" those html it show me video link and play them. And that is working fine. But when I generate .chm and from there try to play, it show me dialog box for downloading file. What I want is to play that video also in generated .chm file.

How to do that?

Also have to tall that when I generate "Web help" file, it's working (it play video).

What to configure to play video in .chm file?

Answer (score 2):

Use **Insert** >> **Multimedia** to embed the SWF file in a help topic.

If it still doesn't work, make sure the SWF file is listed in the project manager.  If it is not listed, manually include the SWF file as a baggage file in your RoboHelp project by right-clicking the folder where you want to have it and select **New** >> **Baggage file**

Comment: thnx for replay .... i have those problem cause swf want play inside google chrome (which is my default browseer), now everyting work ok (cause i change browser), .... but thnx for answare

Answer (score 1):

Place a frame in your html code and the video inside of it. The video will now display in place with a player.

I prefer not to use the swf path because not all computers can use it and I heard it was being phased out.